Distribution of a random variable conditional on its being a maximum or not
Consider the random variables $\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_D$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Assume they are continuous. Let
$$
Y=\sum_{d=1}^D d\times \mathbb{1}\{\epsilon_d=\max_{j=1,\dots, D} \text{ }\epsilon_j\}.
$$
I am interested in the distribution of $
\epsilon_j$ conditional on $Y$.
This is a "complicated" distribution to characterise. Suppose for instance to condition on $Y=1$. Then, I want to characterise the distribution of $\epsilon_j$ conditional on the set   $\{\omega\in \Omega: \epsilon_1(\omega)=\max_{j=1,\dots, D} \text{ }\epsilon_j(\omega)\}$.
Questions:

Is the distribution of $\epsilon_j$ conditional on $Y=h$ a truncated distribution for any $j,h$?
I've been told that the distribution of $\epsilon_j$ conditional on $Y=h$ is "simple" if $\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_D$ are i.i.d. Gumbel.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution). Why?

If 1. and 2. cannot be answered in general, let us assume that $\epsilon_1,\dots, \epsilon_D$ are exchangeable (or, if this is not sufficient, i.i.d.).

Your notation makes no sense: it looks like you are just trying to redefine "argmax."  Could you perhaps give a simple example of computing $Y$ to illustrate what you're trying to ask?  Concerning your questions (1) is strange, because there doesn't appear to be any kind of truncation occurring and (2) suggests you might be implicitly assuming the $\epsilon_d$ are independent and maybe even i.i.d.  If so, please state that.

Sorry, I wanted to use $\max$.

Thank you.  But we need more clarification.  If you aren't assuming iid or something that strong, there's almost nothing one can say generally; and if you are assuming iid (or exchangeability), then the result is immediate from the definitions.

Thanks. Let's assume exchangeability and if, this is not sufficient, i.i.d.ness

This comes down to two questions: (1) what is the distribution of the largest of $D$ iid variables? and (2) what is the distribution of a variable given that it's not the largest of them?  Both are answered by the basic theory of [tag:order-statistics].  Intuitively, the answer to (2) is a version of the parent distribution that has been pushed a bit towards smaller values -- so I can see why you referenced truncation -- but this is not a form of truncation, because any value in the support of the distribution is still possible.

Thanks. If you or other users could formalise this discussion in an answer, it would be very helpful.

This is a semi-informal answer for Q2. Consider the case of $\epsilon_1,\cdots,\epsilon_D\overset{iid}{\sim}\text{Gumbel}(\mu,\beta)$, with $D\geq 2$. Then, as $\epsilon_j$ are absolutely continuous, $Y$ is almost surely equal to the index of their maximum. Let $[D]=\{1,2,\dots,D\}$, then:
$$
Y \overset{as}{=} \arg\max_{j\in [D]}\epsilon_j.
$$
Now, the CDF of the maximum of $D\geq 2$ i.i.d. Gumbel-distributed variables, $X=\max_{j\in [D]}\epsilon_j$, is:
$$
P_{X}(x) = \prod_{j\in[D]} P_\epsilon(x) = \exp\left\{-D\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(x-\mu)\right]\right\}  = \exp\left\{-\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(x-\mu-\beta\log D)\right]\right\} .
$$
This is the CDF of a Gumbel$(\mu+\beta\log D,\beta)$ distribution.
Case 1: $j=h$. The statement $Y=h$ is almost surely equivalent to the statement "$\epsilon_h$ is the maximum", so:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_h\leq z\mid Y=h) \overset{as}{=} P_{X}(z), \text{ for } h\in [D]
$$
Case 2: $j\neq h$. Fix $\epsilon_h=e_h$, and apply the Law of Total Expectation. One gets that:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z\mid Y=h) \overset{as}{=}\mathbb{E}_{e_h\sim\epsilon_h}\left[\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z\mid X\leq e_h)\right]=\mathbb{E}_{e_h\sim\epsilon_h}\left[\frac{\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z, X\leq e_h)}{\mathbb{P}(X\leq e_h)}\right] 
$$
Let $W=\max_{i\in [D]\setminus\{j \}}\epsilon_i$, which is independent from $\epsilon_j$, and notice:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z, X\leq e_h) = \mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z, \epsilon_j\leq e_h,W\leq e_h) = \mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq \min\{z,e_h\})\cdot\mathbb{P}(W\leq e_h)
$$
Thus:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z, X\leq e_h)}{\mathbb{P}(X\leq e_h)} &= \frac{\exp\left\{-\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(\min\{e_h,z\}-\mu)\right]\right\}}{\exp\left\{-\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(e_h-\mu-\beta\log D)\right]\right\}}\\
&\,\times \exp\left\{-\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(e_h-\mu-\beta\log (D-1))\right]\right\}\\
&=\begin{cases} 
1 & z> e_h\\
\exp\left\{-\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(z-\mu)\right]+\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(e_h-\mu)\right]\right\} & z\leq e_h
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $P_\epsilon(z)=\exp\left\{-\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(z-\mu)\right]\right\}$, then:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{e_h\sim\epsilon_h}\left[\frac{\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z, X\leq e_h)}{\mathbb{P}(X\leq e_h)}\right] = I_1(z) + P_\epsilon(z)\cdot I_2(z),
$$
with $I_1,I_2$ being marginalizations over the distribution of the maximum $p_X$:
$$
I_1(z) = \int_{-\infty}^z 1\cdot p_X(e_h)\, \text{d}e_h= \exp\left\{-\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(z-\mu-\beta\log D)\right]\right\} = P_X(z)
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_2(z) &= \int_z^{\infty} \exp\left\{\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(e_h-\mu)\right]\right\}\cdot p_X(e_h)\, \text{d}e_h\\
&= \frac{D}{(D-1)\beta}\int_z^{\infty}\exp\left\{-\beta^{-1}(e_h-\mu-\beta\log(D-1))-\exp\left[-\beta^{-1}(e_h-\mu-\beta\log(D-1))\right]\right\}\, \text{d}e_h \\
&=\frac{D}{D-1}\left[1-P_W(z) \right].
\end{aligned}
$$
Taking into account that $P_\epsilon(z)P_W(z)=P_X(z)$, one has:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z\mid Y=h) \overset{as}{=} P_X(z) + \frac{D}{D-1}P_\epsilon(z)[1-P_W(z)] = \frac{D}{D-1}P_\epsilon(z) -\frac{1}{D-1}P_X(z)
$$
This is indeed a proper CDF, as it fulfills:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{z\rightarrow -\infty} \mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z\mid Y=h) &= \frac{D}{D-1}\times 0 -\frac{1}{D-1}\times 0 = 0\\
\lim_{z\rightarrow +\infty} \mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z\mid Y=h) &= \frac{D}{D-1}\times 1 -\frac{1}{D-1}\times 1 = 1\\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} z} \mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z\mid Y=h) &\geq 0, \text{ for } D\geq 2,\beta>0 
\end{aligned}
$$
More interestingly, if $D>>0$, when $j\neq h$, one has that $\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z\mid Y=h)\approx P_\epsilon(z)$. This is, if $D$ is large, and we know $j$ is not the maximum index, then $\epsilon_j$ is just plain Gumbel$(\mu,\beta)$. Putting all together:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_j\leq z\mid Y=h) \overset{as}{=} \begin{cases}
0 & h\not\in [D] \\
P_X(x) & j=h\in [D]\\
\frac{D}{D-1}P_\epsilon(z) -\frac{1}{D-1}P_X(z) & j\neq h\in [D]\\
\end{cases}
$$
All comments welcomed.

Applying the solution in the post by Matt F. would make extremely short work of this, obviating most of the algebra and giving better insight.

@whuber I think "insight" was exactly what was lacking in the previous comments, along formalization, which the OP asked kindly for.

As you wish.  Some people do indeed find pages of algebraic calculation to be helpful--although I would continue to maintain that very few achieve insight that way.  But a request related to "along formalization" is not something I find in the question itself.

Any ideas on Q1?

To write down the equation line for case 1, do you use the fact that the variables are i.i.d.? I understand that you need i.i.d. Gumbel to get that specific distribution for the max, but I wonder if just the equation line $...=P_X(z)$ requires i.i.d.ness.
